# skipping extern for const global still works fine

Tags: c++, constants, global, extern

It is said that for const variables to be referred from outside(i.e. to have external linkage), `extern` keyword is mandatory. So:

```
const int f = 3; // Definition of f with internal linkage (due to const)
extern const int g; // Declaration of g with external linkage
```

If that is correct then how does the following still work fine:
In s1.cpp I have declared and initialized `const int a=9` without `extern`:

## s1.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"h1.h"
using namespace std;

//This is a global variable
const int a=9; // No Extern here

int main()
{
        cout<<a;
        something();
        return 0;
}
```

## h1.h

```
#ifndef H1_H
#define H1_H
extern const int a; //this extern is anyways required
void something();
#endif
```

But here is s2.cpp i can still access `a` without any problem.

## s2.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"h1.h"
using namespace std;


void something()
{
        cout<<"Inside something its : "<<a;  //No problem here. Why?
}
```

Can someone please clarify?

I ran it on linux
gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)

Compiled as  :
g++ s1.cpp s2.cpp -o out

Output as :
9Inside something its : 9indlin1738!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)

Comment: You need to specify **your compiler and your build command(s)**. Otherwise the behavior is not reliably reproducible.

Comment: Voting to close as lacking reproducible example (see above comment).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you included `h1.h` in `s1.cpp`, so (concerning your question) you have something like:

```
extern const int a;
const int a = 9;
```

Which means that `a` is declared to have external linkage and is then defined and initialized here, so `a` is thus visible in the other module `s2.cpp` which only includes `h1.h`:

```
extern const int a;
```

Comment: Well then in which scenario do you think will make me prepend the keyword extern without which it will throw the error?